# Is A recommended over/to B?

Tags: prepositions

I need to ask someone regarding a diet programme. He/she has read the book which contains the diet programme. Which one below would be correct:

> According to the book, is boiled food recommended **over** fried food?

> According to the book, is boiled food recommended **to** fried food?

Questions:

1. While there might be ways to say it in a better way, I would want to know which would be grammatically correct. Chances are both are wrong.
2. Optionally, feel free to express the same thing in a better way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this situation, "recommended **over**" is correct.

"Recommended to" would mean that you suggested B should use A. In this case, you would be asking if fried food was told to eat boiled food. Which doesn't make much sense.

If you want to use the word "to", you could use it with "preferable". E.g. "Is boiled food preferable to fried food?". But I think in this case "recommended over" is the best choice.

Another option is "Does the book recommend boiled food over fried food?" which would shorten the sentence and potentially make it clearer.

Comment: I was confused because I think it is correct to write *preferred A to B*. Thanks for your answer. I will accept it soon.

Comment: Preferred A to B works because the comparison is part of the definition of the verb(to prefer - like one thing better than another). This is not the case with recommend so you need to add the comparison in by using "over". "Over" here means similar to "more than"and that is where the comparison comes from.